# How to get weight and price from EAN 13 UPC barcode android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, zxing

I am using android library zxing for reading EAN 13 barcode but i could not get the price, weight details from scanning barcode.
[image]

Comment: I have also used google services vision it also not provides this info

Answer (score 3):

This code is probably unique to the store in question.

I've worked at a grocery before in Europe and it happens that the system we used was this for a 13-digit barcode (not EAN-13, but it looks similar):

```
[ 2 1 0  -   X X X X - Y Y Y - Z Z Z ]
  ^^^^^      ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
Weightable   Internal  KG      Gram
  Prefix     Product   weight  weight
             Barcode
```

So let's say the grocery store marks Gouda cheese internally with the code `3456` and you bought 1.794 kg, the barcode would be this:

[image: 210345600179]

You're probably best to either ask the store how they manage weighable products or buy a lot of different products and use trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the details about the product just by scanning the barcode. The library you have used just returns the value of the barcode which is "226001001958". You can also use the library to get the type of barcode you have scanned, for example, EAN 13 in your case. If the barcode had the price and weight in it then the text which would have been returned to you after scanning would have contained the price and weight as well. For scanning EAN 13 barcodes and getting their details you must have access to some database where the details of the scanned barcode are present. For example, Open Food Facts has a huge database of barcodes for food products and you can use this database since it is open source.

Comment: EAN 13 has sub types
in the above image last digit 8 = checksum
Three digits before last digit we have 0.195 = weight
But not every EAN 13 has the weight value how i can identity a type which EAN 13 has weight value or which has not.
Is there any logic behind it.

Comment: @Fahad No, because its no part of the EAN13 standard that the last 3 digits is weight.  The standard is GSM id, then manufacturer id, then product id.  The weight defined in the standard is the checksum weight of various digits, not the product weight.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number#Product_code